# Unable to submit a page loaded in Jquery model

Tags: jquery, asp.net, popup, modal-dialog

I am loading an aspx page in Jquery model from Master page,Page is loading fine in popup. but Pop up is not firing any server side events.

**Master Page code**

```
<div id="Exceptionsdialog"></div>  


function OpenExceptions() {
    $('#Equipmentdialog').load('Popups/Test1.aspx', function () {
       $(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            height: 400
        });
    });
}
```

But none of the server methods are firing, or 
when I submit the page or any button click event getting an error saying the resource not found.

```
<Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false"  CodeBehind="Exceptions.aspx.cs" Inherits="LabSafe.Web.Popups.Exceptions" />
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenJquerypopup() {
        alert("Hello");
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div_assetSearchBar">
        <asp:Button runat="server"  id="btn_ViewExceptions" Text="View Exceptions"  OnClick="btn_ViewExceptions_Click" />
    </div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odzTz.jpg)

Comment: Your format is all messed up.

Comment: where is your  > at ur page language???

Comment: I hope you have your OpenExceptions() function inside some <script> tags.

Comment: Yes it is inside the script , 
I have button on the page when I click that,OpenExceptions() function is called , and the page Popups/Test1.aspx is loaded.

Comment: loaded Popups/Test1.aspx is not responding to any functions, or not able to submit the page to code behind , it errors out with resource not found.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post,. tried a lot to format the code. didn't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery modals are created by cloning the DOM elements and placing them at the of the body tag.
This create valid DOM elements and it works fine on the client side.

However for asp.net controls to send events, they must be inside the form tag(asp.net creates only one form tag).

The solution is to create the dialog and then place the elements back into the form tag.

```
function OpenExceptions() {
    $('#Equipmentdialog').load('Popups/Test1.aspx', function () {
       $(this).dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 900,
            height: 400
        });
       $('#Equipmentdialog').parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
    });
}
```

Your server events should now fire perfectly.